# Conflict between ctypes and matplotlib

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, ctypes

I'm trying to use some functions provided by a C library through ctypes. The code is like this:

```
from ctypes import *

astdll = cdll.LoadLibrary('mylib.dylib')
```

This is working fine, but as soon as I import pylab or other matplotlib modules I get an error like this:

```
python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    astdll = cdll.LoadLibrary('mylib.dylib')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(mylib.dylib, 6): initializer function 0x7fff8883a26e not in mapped image for /Users/xxx//mylib.dylib
```

This problem occurs under OS X Mavericks. It works fine under Linux and Windows.

Comment: You should remove one of your current tags and replace it with osx as you say it is a mac-only problem and put that detail in the title.